# my website shows javascript slider and image gallery different depending on url

Tags: javascript, html

If the url is https://sitenameurl everything works fine, but with https://www.sitenameurl sliders and image gallery don't show. Text and other images not included with javascript are show ok but not the ones that should be added using javascript.

No error on console to fight with. HELP!!
[Site without www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfK0Z.jpg)[site with www](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8be4K.jpg)

Comment: Please may you include everything _in the question itself_ rather than making us click a link to a website? --- "The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."

Comment: The problem is that javascript functions that involve images dont show when the url of the site includes "www" in it. But without www everything works ok. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It's seem that your content resides on main domain named as  https://sitenameurl & you want it on subdomain https://www.sitenameurl which has no content.

You can do it either by htaccess file to redirect https://www.sitenameurl on https://sitenameurl.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Waqar, I had found the problem: I made a javascript code that depending on the url was triggering some functions to show images and sliders. I didn`t include the url with www and so nothing happend!! Fool of me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Waqar, I had found the problem: I made a javascript code that depending on the url was triggering some functions to show images and sliders. I didn`t include the url with www and so nothing happend!! Fool of me